# Barcode with multiple sets of information that is able to tab automatically

Tags: google-sheets, barcode-scanner, code39

Is there a way to create a barcode that is "PartNumber" and then "Line" and then when the part number is scanned into google sheets it is broken up? So for example, the operator would scan a barcode that is pre made that would have both the partnumber and line in it (Line 2 of Photo). However, I'm wondering if there is a way that either the scanner/barcode can be split up so it enters/tabs after part number and then goes to line and enters the line which is from the barcode. Any help or clarification is needed. Thanks. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: Incorporate a program in your application that parses the notified barcode data and determines which field the data is in.